# Removing all occurrencs of a word in a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, applet

Im trying to get a method that remove's all occurrences of a word from a Linked List (words). The method I have made removes all occurrences, but not the first one? Here is my remove method:

```
public void removeAll(){
    for(int x = 0; x < words.size(); x++){
        if(words.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(inputWord)){
            words.remove(x);
        }
    }
    out2.setText("Word '" + inputWord + "' all occurrence's have been removed.");
    System.out.println(words);
}
```

If words was:

```
 words = "add","hello","add","add"
```

the output after running the removeAll for "add" would be:

```
 words = "add","hello"
```

Anyone have an idea as to why the first occurrence would not have been removed? Thanks!

Comment: Iterate the list in reverse.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why your code isn't removing the first one. But do iterate in reverse, or use an Iterator.

Comment: The internal array rearranges itself if modifications are done in an arrayList.So better use a Set or iterator to remove duplicates

Comment: I strongly recommend you step through this with a debugger.  I'm sure you'll see immediately what the issue is.

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't `"hello", "add"`?  I think it's actually the last one that you're failing to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you iterate forwards through a list like this and, remove items, you won't remove all adjacent matching items.

For example, if your list is `[add, add]` and you are removing `add`:

- Index is 0 initially, list is `[add, add]`.
- You find `add` at index 0.
- Remove element 0, now the list is `[add]`.
- Increment index, now `index == 1`.
- Index is now greater than or equal to the list size, so you break the loop
- Final list is `[add]`.

So effectively you "skipped over" the second add.

One way to fix this is to decrement `index` after you've removed an element.
Some people (citation needed) frown upon changing the iteration variable inside the body of the for loop. It makes the correctness a bit harder to reason about.

Another way is to iterate the list in reverse, which works because you're not changing the part of the list which you are yet to check:

```
for(int x = words.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--){
```

However, the best approach is to use an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<String> it = words.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  if (it.next().equalsIgnoreCase(inputWord)) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

Note that `LinkedList.get(int)` is an `O(list.size())` operation, so you don't really want to be using that to access your elements in sequence. An `Iterator` can be implemented to exploit knowledge of the internal implementation of the list to allow efficient iteration and removal.

Comment: This worked brilliant thank you! Iv never used an Iterator before so will have to do abit more research into them. Thank you!